# Differential equation non homogeneous

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Pls help me with this
$$2y''–y'–3y= 5e^{3x/2}$$
I've solved the $yc$ part but the particular solution is given me zero
I also try to use $y=Axe^{3x/2}$ but I keep getting $x$ in my answer please help

Comment: $y_p=Ase^{3x/2}$ should work fine for the particular solution

Comment: @Aryadeva: Do you mean $y_p=Axe^{3x/2}$?

Comment: Yes sorry for the typo @Joe

Comment: Hi Best, the particular solution does not work because the complementary function is $y=Ae^{-x}+Be^{3x/2}$. The particular solution can't be of the form $y=Ce^{(3/2)x}$, because then the overall solution would be $y=Ae^{-x}+De^{3x/2}$ for another constant $D=B+C$. In other words, because the complementary function contains the "particular solution", you haven't actually added anything to the solution.

Comment: Check : $y=xe^{3x/2}+c_1e^{3x/2}+c_2e^{-x}$

Answer (score 3):

$$2y''–y'–3y= 5e^{3x/2}$$
Substitute $y=ve^{3x/2}$ the DE becomes:
$$2v''+5v'=5$$
$$\implies v=c_1e^{-5x/2}+c_2+x$$
This is easier to solve.
The particular solution you tried should give the correct answer:
$$y_p=Axe^{3x/2}$$
$$\implies A=1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y[x] =\dfrac  1{25} E^{3 x/2} (-2 + 5 x) + E^{3 x/2} C[1] + E^{-x} C[2]$$ is the correct answer according to Mathematica. Maybe the method of "variation of the constant" might help.